# angular2 http.post method throws typeerror{} exception

Tags: oauth, ionic-framework, angular, angular-promise, ionic2

I tried to change the existing angularjs library to angular2 for my need. http.post method in the below code throws TypeError {} as exception. Someone please help as i am stuck on this.

```
login() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(typeof jsSHA !== "undefined") {
      var signatureObj = (new OauthUtility()).createSignature("POST", this.magentoOptions.baseUrl+"/oauth/initiate", this.oauthObject, {oauth_callback: "http://localhost/callback"}, this.magentoOptions.clientSecret, null);                                   
      let headersInitiate = new Headers();
      headersInitiate.append('Authorization',signatureObj.authorization_header);
      headersInitiate.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      let url = this.magentoOptions.baseUrl + "/oauth/initiate";
      let callback = "oauth_callback=http://localhost/callback";

      try{
        this.http.post(url, callback,{headers: headersInitiate})
         .subscribe(
          (result) => {
          console.log("i am inside");
          var rParameters = (result).split("&");
                            .....
      }
      catch(Exception){
        console.log(Exception)
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like that:

```
var signatureObj = (new OauthUtility()).createSignature("POST", 
     this.magentoOptions.baseUrl+"/oauth/initiate", this.oauthObject,
     {oauth_callback: "http://localhost/callback"},
     this.magentoOptions.clientSecret, null);    let headersInitiate = new Headers();

headersInitiate.append('Authorization',
          signatureObj.authorization_header);
headersInitiate.append('Content-Type',
          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let url = this.magentoOptions.baseUrl + "/oauth/initiate";

let payload = ' ... ';
this.http.post(url, payload,{headers: headersInitiate})
    .subscribe(
      (result) => {
        console.log("i am inside");
        var rParameters = (result).split("&");
        (...)
      });
```

Here are the comments I would have on your code:

- The second parameter of the `post` method should be a string corresponding to the payload not a callback. I see from your headers that you want to send url-encoded form, so you need to create it by your own
- The `try catch` isn't necessary since executing an HTTP is asynchronous and errors can be "catched" within the second parameter (another callback) of the `subscribe` method.
- You don't need at all a promise. For HTTP, Angular2 uses observables under the hood. They target asynchronous processing as well.

After fixing all of this, I think that you won't have error anymore...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks @Thierry for your reply. I have passed parameters through variable callback in my POST method. 
 let callback = "oauth_callback=http://localhost/callback";
Sorry that i missed it in my previous code.
I didnt get my errors catched in the second parameter of subscribe method. Thats the reason i have included try catch. May be i will try excluding promises.

Comment: I tried by removing promise and i am facing issue. The reason for the issue is http is undefined. I have included @Injectable as well, but still the issue remains same. Please help

Comment: Did you add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` within the second parameter of the `bootstrap` function?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to get inside the function :)

Answer (score 0):

I found to stuck even after proceeding with the above all steps. The complete solution is as follows.
Remove try catch block and promise as suggested by Thierry.
Use **dependency injection** of http inside the constructor as follows to define http.

```
import {Http,HTTP_PROVIDERS,Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injector} from "angular2/core";
 constructor() {

        var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
        this.http = injector.get(Http);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you inject `Http` from constructor? This can be done when registering HTTP_PROVIDERS in the `bootstrap` function or in components that use the `http` object. This way you don't need to explicitly refer the `Injector`...

Comment: I am creating anguar2 library for my ionic2 application. Since this acts as a service, Http injected in constructor didnt work. It remains undefined. Thats the reason for error in my code. When i inject with injector, it works fine.

Comment: Did you add the `@Injectable` decorator to your service?

Comment: Yes i did. But it didnt work. As well i tried using @Inject(HTTP) http: Http in my constructor. I have no idea about why it didnt work.

Comment: I should ;-) Did you use this: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);`?

Comment: Okay I see. You should declare HTTP providers into the `providers` attribute of your app component. See these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760422/how-to-user-angular-2-service-with-ionic-2 and https://github.com/barbatus/ionic2-meteor/blob/master/bootstrap.ts#L39. I think the first one is enough... If you want to have more details about how hierarchical injectors of Angular2 works, you could have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397