# How to inject angular service in controller in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on Ionic Framework and there is a requirement that I need to inject the angular services in controller to get the data or perform any CRUD operation in backend. Please Let me know how I can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876748/service-injection-into-controller-with-angularjs look here

Comment: Have you got any sample code or any attempts to show us?

Comment: Thanks Mohan.. Its working for me..

Answer (score 0):

`Ionic Framework` is build upon `angular.js`, so there s no difference in doing this in `Ionic`.

Its simple like

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp',['ionic']);

myapp.service('MyService',['$http', function($http) {
   return {
       doSomeThing: function() {
           // do something here with $http or whatever
       },
       doSomeThingElse: function() {
       }
}
]);

myapp.controller('MyController',['MyService',function(MyService) {


   MyService.doSomeThing();

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ionic2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760422/how-to-user-angular-2-service-with-ionic-2) is an example on how to inject a Service into a controller; note the `@Injectable` decorator in the Service, the `[providers]` parameter of the `@Page` decorator in the Controller, and how the service instance is a parameter of the `constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by @mJunaidSalaat,

1. You need to inject IONIC module to angular app module
2. The remaining implementation will be as it is in Angular

As per below, you can:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
```