# Ionic 2 ionicBootstrap not loading in angularjs 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on ionic 2 app and using angularjs 2. Now I need to implement ng2-translate and I am following https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/ng2-translate/ doc.

But whenever I import ionicBootstrap from ionic-angular it gives me error

> module ionic-angular has no exported member ionicBootstrap.

[image]

Here's my ionic info:

[image]

I can use some help here guys thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34762065/5928577

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya not sure how this answer solves my problem...I need to import ionicBootstrap so that I can use ng2-translate...the code in snapshot I posted in my question should work but its not working

Comment: for ng2-translate you no need to import ionicBootstrap. check documentation here https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/ng2-translate/

Comment: Ionic2 is not using ionicBootstrap anymore, check step 12 & 14 of https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-rc0

Comment: @Ivaro18 yes I just get to know from there official repo that there doc was outdated