# Ionic 2/Angular 2 global variables

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I just started using Ionic2/Angular 2 and I'm a bit confused.
Let's say I have a variable in a class like this:

```
export class HomePage {
    array: string[]; 
}
```

and I would like to use the data in the array in another class but not change it. How would I export the variable array from class HomePage to another class?

Comment: Dependency injection

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: You can use a shared service. Please take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760422/how-to-use-angular-2-service-with-ionic-2/38036031#38036031).

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use Global Service/shared Service , firslt set your global variable with value globaly in your app than you are able to use that service anywheer in your app.

let suppose this is our Global service

```
export class GlobalService {
    array: string[]; 
}

export class HomePage {
    array: any[] = [];

    constructor(private global: GlobalService){
        this.array = this.global.array; 
    }
}

export class SecondPage {
    array: any[] = [];

    constructor(private global: GlobalService){
        this.array = this.global.array; 
    }
}
```

you can inject that GloablService globally in your app. like in the main module than no need to add service in the list of providers everytime.
just import this and intilize in the constructor and access their method and variables

Comment: where do I put: export class GlobalService {
    array: string[]; 
}

Comment: Make a separate file for the same and add the reference in app.module.ts file

Comment: sorry man I'm a noob when it comes to Angular 2, can you explain how  I can add a reference in app.module.ts and where would I create the GlobalService.ts file assuming I'm using Ionic 2

Comment: please take a look at new angular CLI project structure there you will find app.module.ts file and you will know about dependency injection. also create GloablService at global level/root level. sorry i dont have any idea about ionic i know about only angular2.

Comment: thanks man! so I'm gessing I'll have to add it as a provider right?

Comment: this is what I see in my app.module.ts:

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [ Storage, {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}

Comment: Exactly you have to add in the list of providers I hope you get it

Comment: says can't find name GlobalService :(