# Ionic V2 - Creating a Service

Tags: angular, ionic2

Anyone knows how to create an angular2 service with Ionic2 v2.1.0 ?

Already tried a lot of things but keep getting errors.

I followed some answers from here [How to use angular 2 service with Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760422/how-to-use-angular-2-service-with-ionic-2) but it doesn't work...

Here is my code

DataBaseService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class DataBaseService {
    constructor() {
    }

    execSQL() {
        console.log('call works');
    }
}
```

Imported in "app.component.ts"

```
import { DataBaseService } from 'DataBaseService';
```

And put it in the @Component of "app.component.ts"

```
@Component({
   templateUrl: 'app.html',
   providers: [DataBaseService]
})
```

If I run the app this way, I get the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "DataBaseService"
```

Comment: Is the path to DatabaseService correct?

Comment: are you sure of the path?

Comment: yes!

the DataBaseService.ts is in the same path of app.component.ts !

Comment: then the  statement is `import { DataBaseService } from './DataBaseService';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service file is in the same location do

```
import { DataBaseService } from './DataBaseService';
```

You are getting the error because it is looking for a module when you give it directly as `import { DataBaseService } from 'DataBaseService';`

Answer (score 1):

regarding https://angular.io/styleguide add providers to NgModule and them in component constructor. services should be initialized when app bootstraps.

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [MyModules]
 declerations: [MyComponent]
 providers: [MyService]
});
```

Comment: True..but only if you need a singleton service..it can be se in component also

Comment: Thanks for the help, suraj answer was the right for my case!

Comment: Singleton service way isn't working for me as well looking for answers regarding it :)